# Doctrine counter cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How is the best way to implement counter cache in Doctrine?

In Ruby on Rails: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this *out of the box* at this moment.

If I had to this, I would try first using [event listeners](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html) similar to [Gedmo's Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions).

Whenever an entity would be added or removed from the relation, the listener would update the field in charge of keeping trace of the counting.